# Elementor Library: Not connected (cURL error 28: Connection timed out ...)

Tags: wordpress, curl, elementor

I'm having an issue when trying to load templates in Elementor. The template loading page is stuck in a loading loop.

These are the errors in Wordpress -> Elementor -> System Info -> Debug

```
Errors: 
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
            at http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/js/editor.min.js?ver=2.1.6 - 2:27412
            2018-08-01 15:39 +00:00

        TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null
            at http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/elementor/assets/js/editor.min.js?ver=2.1.5 - 2:27412
            2018-07-29 15:58 +00:00
            x 2 times
```

[System Info](https://pastebin.com/75r4tbwM)

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same issue it helped to disconnect my elementor account and therefor its licence. Reactivating also reactivated the connection to the template library which seems to be handled seperately from the rest of the elementor plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Using Elementor 2.1.4, I was not able to resolve this issue by reinstalling the plugin, reactivate the license, disabling other plugins, using the 'Sync Library' tool.

What worked for me was replacing

```
  s:10:"categories";N;
```

with

```
  s:10:"categories";a:0:{}
```

in the `option_value` field of the entry in the `wp_otions` table in the database where

```
 option_name = 'elementor_remote_info_library'
```

This value gets updated from time to time, so to avoid the categories getting set to null again you might also want to commment out the following line in `wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/api.php@111` right before the `update_option( self::LIBRARY_OPTION_KEY, ...)`:

```
    $info_data['library']['categories'] = json_decode( $info_data['library']['categories'] );
```

which causes this issue, as the categories already are available as array instead of JSON at this point.